# How do I get coefficients of a random forest model?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, regression-coefficients

I am using `randomForest` to generate a model, and at the end I don't know how I can get the final coefficients that the model is fitting. I know that for linear regression, you just type `summary(lm)` where `lm` is your model, and you get the coefficients.

Comment: you can get coefficients for linear models only

Comment: There are no coefficients in random forests. I recommend reading an introduction to classification and regression trees to understand what's happening there.

Comment: thanks for your response. Is it possible to combine linear regression modeling and random forest? i am trying to develop a simple regression model for prediction of rainfall but am having difficulties choosing the suitable methodology.most reviews are discouraging the use of stepwise regression methods. I tried using caret but it did not work out. when i used randomForest i was able to get the model and predicted values but not the coefficients of the predictors. how can i go about this?

Comment: If all you are interested about is prediction, then you don't need to worry about any parameters. If you need a measure of the importance of regressors, you can use `importance=TRUE` in `randomForest()` of the eponymous R package (I assume this is what you are using?). Look through the literature on random forests to understand how these measures of importance are calculated. Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelMayer: no, unfortunately not. I'd be interested if anyone knows such a reference.

Comment: I disagree that the approach used in random forest does not apply to linear models. It actually works pretty well in some cases. Here is a package which implements random GLMs http://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/RGLM/ The link includes some nice tutorials. It is interpretable so it could be of interest to @ckumbuyo too. One of the main advantages of using random forest is that it is totally non-parametric, no assumptions. It is inmune to some transformations of the covariates and is resistant to noise. I recommend this article by Breiman called: Statistical modelling: the two cultures.

Comment: While this question was a little off-base in confusion randomForest with a regression-style equation, I would still be interested in extracting the tree-based logic from a `randomForest` object for the purpose of using that prediction logic in some `shiny` use cases where the actual `predict` function with the `randomForest` object is not viable

Comment: rF$importance will give you list of variables with their corresponding MeanDecreaseGini, if this helps.

Answer (score 5):

@Community brought this question from the past. Unfortunately the both answers from 2014 do not answer the question. The answer to the question is in @StephanKolassa comment: there are is no meaningful concept of coefficient for RF (except the importance measure of RF).

I also must add that I found @MichaelMayer comment that "random forests are not very useful in combining strong learners such as regression trees" very surprising. In my *very limited* experience with regression, RF is always a competitive algorithm (together with MLP) - I have not yet used GBM or Gaussian Processes for regression.

Comment: I fully agree with you and thus removed my old comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate coefficients one at a time. This makes the most sense if you are approaching the problem from a causal inference perspective.

The idea is to estimate y ~ x to predict hat{y}. Then estimate in a linear model, (y - hat{y}) ~ z. This is analogous to E[E[y|x]|z] = E[y|z,x], which will yield an estimate of the effect of z on y given x, under some standard selection assumption.

In theory you could do this piecewise regression throughout, but note your SEs will be incorrect (and possibly meaningless since it's not clear what sampling theory is motivated them). Anyway these should probably should be bootrapped, assuming bootstrapping random forests makes sense...